# Как проверить Switch Case на 2 записи в разных регистрах?

Tags: c#

Допустим у меня есть такая функция:

```
var TextInput = Console.ReadLine();
switch (TextInput)
{
  case "Help":
  Console.ReadLine();
  break;
}
```

Мне нужно чтобы пользователь мог вписывать не только с Большой буквы `Help` но и с маленькой в нижнем регистре.

Просто как пример ( не знаю как это записать точно )

```
case "Help": "help"
Console.ReadLine();
break;
```

Как это реализовывается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На случай если нужно учитывать не только регистр, но и возможные опечатки или синонимы

```
switch (TextInput)
{
  case "hеlp": //тут 'е' русская
  case "help": //тут 'e' английская
    Console.ReadLine();
    break;
}
```

Пример в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#the-switch-section)

Comment: Спасибо) Моментальный ответ)

Answer (score 3):

Можете привести к одному регистру, тогда не важно, в каком регистре юзер будет вводить.

```
var TextInput = Console.ReadLine();
switch (TextInput.ToLower())
{
    case "help":
        Console.ReadLine();
        break;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению это не помогло :(

Comment: @GooliveR проверьте буквы `e` и `p`  - help и hеlp только выглядят одинаково

Comment: @GooliveR я же вам только идею написал, а не готовый код. Поправил ответ, пробуйте.